# Intercept keyboard input

Tags: c#, windows, google-translate

I am trying to make an automatic English to Spanish translator.

What I want to do, is when someone types on the keyboard, it cancels what they are typing, and stores it in a string in my C# app.

Whatever the user types will then be translated and retyped (in spanish) using Sendkeys.Send().

It needs to work outside of the application, so if they are using any other app, it will work.

My plan is to have them try to type, then, as they are typing, it translates into Spanish for them.

Comment: Do console.write() instead of writeline(). And when starting the string put /r/n so it starts at the beginning

Comment: As a user, I think this is a terrible idea. I'd definitely want to see what I type, if for no other reason, to confirm that I typed it correctly.

Comment: E.g "ball" in spanish is "pelota". None of these letters can be deciphered to be the other, string lengths are different etc. It'd be better if you just did a dictionary pull. Or used google Translates engine

Comment: why re-invent the wheel so to speak when google translate already does something in a much better fashion than you are proposing geez...

Comment: @FirebladeDan The OP sounds like he wants to do by-word processing - e.g. "stores it in a string". Despite misgivings about the feasibility of such, the core problem (and question) of "How to capture keyboard input?" remains.

Comment: Intercepting key presses is pretty sketchy stuff.  Things get out of hand rather quickly.

Comment: @ryanyuyu No doubt. But either 1) it is possible, in which case there is an answer explaining how; or 2) it is not possible (within the target domain), in which case there is an answer explaining why.

Comment: @user2864740 very true.  I just instinctively cringe when I hear "intercepting key presses"

Comment: @user2864740 - he should show the string regardless. it's the same as typing in your password in *nix boxes. It doesn't show what you typed and if someone interrupts you damn just hit enter and let it fail to try again. Poor ui

Comment: @FirebladeDan While a valid argument/thought, it is irrelevant to the *question* (or core task, when stated as a question) asked.

Comment: @user2864740 True but at the same time, imagine typing several characters in Word and not seeing anything until suddenly a random Spanish word shows up. As a user, you have no idea what you typed until you see the Spanish word and you translate it back to confirm it's the word you wanted. This is a very poor idea. The technical side of using a keyboard hook is surely a duplicate but this question is off-topic anyway so I didn't check.

Comment: @xxbbcc As a user, I might despise such a product (and there is no short list of software I have disliked). As a visitor of StackOverflow, I try to honor the original question/task - and to solicit answers that do the same.

Comment: @xxbbcc And no, asking how to intercept the keyboard (or other input) is not off topic. The [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) covers quite a few examples of "good" and "bad" questions and, while I prefer to see questions that come with code (ie. "Why is this hook not capturing input?"), this question does fit well within on-topic questions.

Comment: @user2864740 It's not off-topic because it's about keyboard hooks (it's a duplicate - a quick search turned up several questions). I also think it's off-topic because it asks for a tutorial. I voted to close not because I despise the idea (which I do) but because of the above reasons.

Comment: @xxbbcc This question does not ask for a tutorial or other off-site resource. If you have found some good related questions, link them. If you have found a good duplicate, vote to close it as a duplicate. There is no "despise the idea" vote option.

Comment: @user2864740 The top 3 results in this search are all duplicates: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+intercept+keyboard&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 - I can't vote to close as a duplicate because I already voted to close as off-topic (which I think holds).

Answer (score 2):

I'd look into Windows Hooks: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318804. This would be the only way to intercept keystrokes outside of your application. What you would do is receive all key messages using a lowlevel keyboard hook. For any keystrokes you don't care about you would call CallNextHookEx. For keystrokes you do care about you would return a dummy return (generally 1). This would keep the keystroke from propagating. You would then save the value of that keystroke and whenever space is heard you would convert the word you have to spanish.

Feel free to message me with any questions you have! I've worked with keyboard and mouse hooks extensively.